# iOS - ARC/Memory management issues with ModalViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I'm writing an app (in iOS 5 using ARC!) that presents several hundred objects within a custom `UIViewController` I've written that a user may scroll through and select, each of which is presented as a thumbnail image that the user may touch.

Each of these objects has associated with it a special `UIViewController` subclass that handles the custom presentation of the information associated with that object.  For example, it might be an image that can be zoomed and panned, or simply some text that needs to be formatted.

Now, each of my image objects has a large image associated with it.  Using the Instruments app to profile my code and running Activity Monitor, I see that these take up roughly 5-10MB each when the custom `UIViewController` subclass loads and the image is displayed.  This is fine for a few images, but eventually my app takes up too much memory and crashes.

I have written in my subclass's `-viewDidUnload` method apparently all of the things necessary to tell ARC to free up this memory, but no memory is being freed until warnings are issued, which typically occurs when the app is about to crash.  A couple of times, I've noticed that if I get close enough to the threshold but don't go over it, the `UIViewController` subclasses that I've previously viewed are eventually flushed from memory, although the `-viewDidUnload` method is not apparently called (rather, the `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` message is sent to my custom `UIViewControllers`).  However, most often, my app crashes as it runs out of memory.

So my core question is, should I assume that an object will be disposed of by ARC as soon as possible, or does it always wait until space becomes tight?  The behavior I want is for the custom view controller and its data to be flushed right away, so that memory never becomes an issue.

I do not believe there are any strong references from objects to my custom view controllers, and I instantiate them in my primary view controller using this code:

```
[self presentViewController:[cObj grabModalViewController]
                   animated:YES completion:nil];
```

where `cObj` is a custom class with the object's information.  `grabModalViewController` simply instantiates an object of the correct type and returns the pointer, so presumably the local reference to the object should be trashed as soon as the method completes.

As a result, I would expect that, when I later call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

the custom view controller that was only pointed to be the primary view controller via `presentedViewController` should be flushed from memory, but this does not happen.

Could this be because I have strong references within my custom view controller object?

Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is to avoid as many memory warnings as possible by managing things better up front, but perhaps this is not the right attitude.

I'd appreciate any suggestions and I'm happy to post any and all code that would be helpful.

Comment: actually I realized I said something rather stupid; obviously if the custom view controllers' memory is every getting reclaimed, then there must not be strong references pointing to this object.  However, I don't understand then why the memory management system is unreliable in that sometimes my app crashes rather than just freeing up the memory that it knows it can.  I guess this is probably indicative of something deeper that's wrong.

Comment: Check to see if [cObj grabModalViewController] is returning an object that is retained.  Or you might have a retain cycle where your modal view controller is retaining a reference to an instance variable in another object.  Either of these will prevent the modal view controllers from being deallocated.

Comment: @timthetoolman thanks for the suggestions -- I'm fairly certain that neither of these is the case, though.  The method body for `[cObj grabModalViewController]` looks like this: `LightboxViewController *newController = [[LightboxImageViewController alloc] init];
        [(LightboxImageViewController *) newController setImageFilename:self.imageFile];
        
        return newController;` where the new LightboxImageViewController has an imageFile property that is `nonatomic, copy`.  I thought that having `retain` would cause problems, but assumed that these would be solved using `copy`.

Comment: Your Lightboxcontroller is alloc/init'd so ARC may be giving you some problems there.  ARC may not be inserting the appropriate release at compile time.

Comment: I want also to note that I've done things like intentionally set all the sub view controller's objects to `nil` when `-viewDidDisappear` is called, hoping this would induce ARC to free the memory, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you get any `- didReceiveMemoryWarning` calls?

Comment: @ott yes--but unfortunately sometimes my app is so close to crashing that it eventually does before memory can be cleared out (which was happening sometimes).  FWIW I figured out *why* I was keeping so many `UIImage` objects in memory -- I was instantiating them using `UIImage imageNamed:` rather than `initWithContentsOfFile`.  Once I made this switch, the memory that my `UIImages` occupy is overwritten each time I instantiate a new image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my core question is, should I assume that an object will be
>   disposed of by ARC as soon as possible, or does it always wait until
>   space becomes tight?

ARC is a compile time technology. It knows nothing about your runtime memory heap. Hence, it cannot wait to release items until space becomes tight. A specific answer to your question is that ARC will release anything as soon as you no longer need it.

Comment: Or, put another way: *ARC is not garbage collection*.